# How to receive string from database with double quotes

Tags: java, string

I need to fetch a query from a database table using ResultSet and use it in my java program for further processing. The query looks like.

```
CREATE INDEX "POLICY_STUDIO_SE"."EL_LMT_FTR_TL ON "PSE"."SE_EL_LMT_FTR_" (NVL("RESOURCE_ID",'@@')) 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "ID"
```

The double quotes(") won't allow me to receive this entire query as java string.

Can anyone provide any suggestions on it?

Comment: Have you tried simple replacing the quotes with single quotes?  How about double-double quotes with an escape \""  <-- like that.

Comment: @durbnpoisn can't change query it is from oracle's meta-data table, when i am fetching this query using resultset's getString("XXXX") method, i need need to receive it in a String type variable. So i can't format it as would only be a sub string to the first double quote.(CREATE INDEX ). If i would have received a full query then i can do that replacing.

Comment: `CREATE INDEX` is a SQL DDL statement, not a **query**. A `SELECT` statement is a query. --- If that statement is sitting as text in a `VARCHAR` column, you *"fetch [...] from a database table using ResultSet"* by calling `rs.getString(...)`. Quotes in the text value will not be a problem. --- Did you mean to ask how to write that SQL statement directly in a Java source file as a String literal? Because that's a totally different question, for which you already got answer, i.e. escape the quotes using ``\``. It also has nothing to do with `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quote like:

```
"\""
```

In your case the full string escaped is:

```
 String s=  "CREATE INDEX \"POLICY_STUDIO_SE\".\"EL_LMT_FTR_TL ON \"PSE\".\"SE_EL_LMT_FTR_\" (NVL(\"RESOURCE_ID\",\'@@\'))"+ 
        "PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS"+ 
        "STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645"+
        "PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)"+
        "TABLESPACE \"ID\"";
```

Comment: @ Aayush Agrawal. I'm sorry I misunderstand what you are asking. I'll change my answer